# c# deserialize json to list results in null when json is empty?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am facing this situation and it is really strange to me.

I have class A has the following

```
public class A
{
   public A()
   {   
      Values = new List<B>();
   }

   public virtual IList<B> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that will read all A records form the db.

```
var all = await GetAll();
```

here is my method

```
public async Task<IList<A>> GetAll(int id1)
{
    var parameters = new[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@ProductTypeId", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = id1},  
    };

    return (await _sqlCommandWrapper.ExecuteReaderAsync("SPName", r => new  A
        {
            values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<B>>(r["Values"].ToString())
        }, parameters)).ToList();
}
```

my db column `r["Values"]` will return json that can be deserialized to list of B class.

Then i am using linq to query all my A:

```
var subitems = all .Where(a=> a.Values .Count > 0).ToList();
```

If my `r["Values"]` return data, it works fine.

however if it is not then `a.Values` is null ?

Any reason, however I defined in my A constructor that `Values = new List<B>();`

Comment: You have a public setter, so somebody must be calling it with a null value.  Change the property to set an explicit field, set a break in the setter, and find out where.  Probably Json.NET is doing it, in which case you can change the setter to treat an incoming null as an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for the issue is, following code which do the Json deserialization replaces the Values of type (`IList<B>`), you are not doing anything with the original list that is instantiated in the constructor

```
values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<B>>(r["Values"].ToString())
```

When `r["Values"].ToString()` is a valid Json it gets deserialized into `IList<B>` which is an assignment call, now when `r["Values"].ToString()` generates a Json that is a mismatch or empty then the result of the following code is Null

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<B>>(r["Values"].ToString())
```

In case you plan to use the List instantiated in the constructor then it should be:

```
Values.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(r["Values"].ToString()))
```

In this case `r["Values"].ToString()` generates the Json for type `B` not `IList<B>`

However this would certainly not work as is, since you are generating a new A, which is then added to `IList<A>` and returned as a Task result, so that part would also need modification

Comment: Welcome, in case it does help in solving the exact issue at hand then please remember to mark this as an answer